# Are all Earth Grounds Equal?

Tags: ground

**Hypothetical:** I have two circuits that are being powered from the same electrical service. They both have a hot and a neutral wire from the same transformer.

- The first circuit *and* the transformer are earth grounded locally with a ground rod.
- The second circuit is earth grounded on the other side of the country with a second ground rod.

Assuming the voltage drop is acceptable for circuit #2:

1. Are these equivalent circuits?
2. What problems could occur when a circuit is grounded elsewhere than where its electrical service is grounded?

---

**Hypothetical Schematic**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5xQKe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Just to clarify, you are talking specifically about **earth** ground. In general, "ground" is any arbitrarily chosen reference point in a circuit.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, yes that is correct. Specifically **earth** ground. Thanks for the clarification edit.

Comment: not same ... circuit #2 does not have neutral tied to ground locally

Comment: Is this a homework question? It reads exactly like one.

Comment: @TonyM, not a homework question -- uni's been done for a few years but it has obviously had an effect. Just a thought I had at work when discussing with clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are these equivalent circuits?

Not really.  The resistance between G and N on CCT#1 is likely to be very low.  It may be less than an ohm.

The resistance between G and N on CCT#2 is likely to be much higher.  With a simple rod hammered into the ground, it could be anything from a few tens of ohms to a few kilohms.  Dirt isn't a good conductor, especially if it's dry.

The first supply would be classified as "TN-S", the second is "TT".

> What problems could occur when a circuit is grounded elsewhere than where its electrical service is grounded?

You haven't said what circuit protection devices CCT#1 and CCT#2 have.  A short between L and G on CCT#1 will cause a large current to flow.  This should trip a circuit breaker or blow a fuse.

A short between L and G on CCT#2 is unlikely to pass enough current to trip a breaker or blow a fuse, unless you have an unusually good earth rod.  Such circuits really need to be protected by an RCD/GFCI to be safe (RCD and GFCI are the same thing under different names).

Comment: Surely the first is not really TN-S if there is a local ground rod? It could be either TN-S or TN-C-S depending on where the earth and neutral are connected (away from the property or as the supply enters the property). However, with the local ground rod it’s not like either of those conventional earthing systems (as used in the UK).

Comment: @Simon B, I did forget to add explicit circuit protection in my diagram. CCT#1 and CCT#2 would each have standard circuit breakers. I'm looking at this from an industrial mindset. So for CCT#2 are you saying the breaker wouldn't trip? Isn't the current to ground what causes the trip though?

Comment: Ground rods can have different resistances to ground. A special meter is used to measure that. Sometime a longer ground rod can provide the low resistance spec'ed for a system. Sometimes a spread-finger system is used when a ground rod cannot be pounded in. There are other methods as well.  https://www.google.com/search?ei=hs9EXbfuFYmQ5wLrq4OgDQ&q=measure+ground+resistance&oq=measure+grou&gs_l=psy-ab.1.3.0l10.170241.177799..182204...10.0..3.235.3085.24j9j1......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..0i71j0i67j0i131j0i10j0i5i30.EWNl4Yi7Ycw#kpvalbx=_b9BEXYTTLIWL5wKPvLWYBQ27

Comment: The problem with earth rods is that the resistance is often too high to trip a circuit breaker.  For example, if the supply is 120V, and the earth resistance is 24 ohms, then only 5A will flow.  That isn't going to be enough to trip most breakers.  That's where an RCD/GFCI comes in.  That will trip at a few milliamps.

Comment: @SimonB, that makes sense. If the ground were tied back to neutral then you'd have a low resistance current pathway and pop the breaker, correct?

Comment: @C.Lange Yes, that's the advantage of having the earth running back to the transformer, and linked to the neutral.

Answer (score 0):

> Are these equivalent circuits?

Yes, with small stipulations.

As far as the circuits go? If they are both going to earth, it will accomplish the same thing. Any fault current will go back to earth as intended. Ground normally doesn't carry current, and is generally used in a fault, while there will be slight variations of voltage depending on where the ground rods are place (even the earths potential isn't *always* at zero volts, but can be *considered to be at zero volts*)

> What problems could occur when a circuit is grounded elsewhere than
>   where its electrical service is grounded?

If there are other circuits that use ground for fault detection then the configuration above may not work. It may also not satisfy local electrical codes so check those. It may also cause ground loops with sensitive equipment if cables were ran between the two devices on separate grounds

Comment: For a major fault to Earth ground, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=28Xq3JulV1o) happens. No, the Earth is not designed to carry current.

Comment: @rdtsc That's probably the **worst place** for a fault! There is a power plant a few miles away from one of the places I lived, about 1600MW. I read an article in the paper that a very small current could be measured in the ground from the transmission lines.

Comment: @Voltage Spike, is dissipating fault current to earth all that is required to make it safe? This scenario doesn't satisfy local codes, I'm aware of that. One code that stood out is that multiple ground rods for a building need to be connected by a ground conductor. If all grounds were equal I didn't think that'd be required.

Comment: @rdtsc, I'm surprised that lasted so long!